Large scale landscape with small-scale details
I would like to make a very large landscape of say 50x50 km that is, close to the camera, still quite detailed, up to the level of meters. The topography of the landscape could be set by two png height maps, one for the 50x50 km scale, one for the close-by details at a scale of 2x2 km, with a subdivision at 0.5 meters close to the camera. How can I best do this? I now use two planes, but it is very hard not to see a seem.
Thanks in advance, Johan
